# Implicit Differentiation Solution Verification

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification, implicit-differentiation

Find $y'$.

$$
\\ \begin{align}
\\5{y}^2 &= \dfrac{2x - 3}{2x + 3}
\\
\\5{y}^2(2x + 3) &= 2x - 3
\\
\\ y(2x+3)&= \dfrac{2x-3}{5y}
\\
\\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}[y(2x + 3)] &= \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}[\dfrac{2x - 3}{5y}]
\\
\\ y'(2x + 3) + 2y &= \dfrac{10y - 5y'(2x - 3)}{{(5y)}^2}
\\
\\ 2xy'+ 3y'+ 2y &= \dfrac{10y - 10xy' + 15y'}{25{y}^2}
\\
\\ 50x{y}^2y' + 75{y}^2y' + 50{y}^3 &= 10y - 10xy' + 15y'
\\
\\ 5(10x{y}^2y' + 15{y}^2y' + 10y^3) &= 5(2y - 2xy' + 3y')
\\
\\ 10x{y}^2y' + 15{y}^2y' + 10{y}^3 &= 2y - 2xy' + 3y'
\\
\\ 10x{y}^2y' + 15{y}^2y' + 2xy' - 3y' &= 2y - 10{y}^3
\\
\\ y'(10x{y}^2 + 15{y}^2 + 2x - 3) &= 2y(1-5{y}^2)
\\
\\ y' &= \dfrac{2y(1-5{y}^2)}{10x{y}^2 + 15{y}^2 + 2x - 3}
\\ \end{align}
$$

I find $y'$ to be $y' = \dfrac{2y(1-5{y}^2)}{10x{y}^2 + 15{y}^2 + 2x - 3}$.

Could someone verify or dispute this?

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: @KittyL Are you sure? Wolfram calculates the derivative to be [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+%285y^2%3D%282x-3%29%2F%282x%2B3%29%29) and additionally finds [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=does+6%2F%285+%283%2B2+x%29^2+y%29+equal+%282y%281-5y^2%29%29%2F%2810xy^2%2B15y^2%2B2x-3%29%3F).

Comment: That is because you didn't tell Wolfram $5{y}^2 = \dfrac{2x - 3}{2x + 3}$ when you ask it to simplify. You would get their answer if you take derivative on both sides at the first step, instead of trying to simplify. Your simplification incorporated some $y^2$ term in your answer. It is not wrong, just more complicated.

Comment: Hmm. Alright. I see where I overcomplicated my solution. I don't think I did it wrong at any point, though. But, clearly more work than necessary.